# How to create a matrix/2D array of subsets?

Tags: arrays, r

I would like to subset my data into a 2D array or a matrix. This is what I've tried:

```
mat <- array(, c(3,3))

for(i in 1:3) {
  mat[i,1] <- subset(df, ...)
  mat[i,2] <- subset(df, ...)
  mat[i,3] <- subset(df, ...)
}
```

But I am getting the warning: `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`. Is this correct and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The error message is being pretty clear. You are trying to place an object with length >1 into a space that only fits a single value. We can't say much more without a reproducible example.

Comment: I am trying to create a matrix of subsets of my data for easy iteration. A matrix where each cell contains a subset of my data.

Comment: No, even if you could do this with matrices (and technically, you probably could) you absolutely should not. There are _countless_ tools for designed specifically for this: `split`/`lapply`, **plyr**, **data.table**, **dplyr**, `by`, `aggregate`, etc etc etc.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with those functions. Which one would you suggest I use? I just want a way to store subsets of my data so that I could iterate over them easily.

Comment: For a beginner, I would start by simply storing the subsets in a list (just use a list instead of a matrix in your above example). Then I'd suggest you start reading about **plyr**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split your data up based on a certain condition or factor, you can do so with split. Let's say you have

```
dd<-data.frame(
   a=runif(100),
   b=runif(100),
   c=sample(c("x","y","z"), 100, replace=T),
   d=sample(c("M","F"), 100, replace=T)
)
```

Then you can split your data with

```
subs<-split(dd, dd$c)
```

to make a list with three elements where the first contain all the rows with "x", the second contains all the rows with "y" and the third all the rows with "z". You can do this with combinations of variables too

```
subs<-split(dd, interaction(dd$c, dd$d))
```

And then if you want, you could run regression on each of those subsets or something

```
reg <- lapply(subs, function(x) lm(b~a, x))
reg[[1]] #to see the results for the first group
```